# SQLite Restrict/Update/cascade

Tags: sqlite

```
"should not be able delete movie if there are any linked data present",
    async done => {
      const movieId = 100;
      const query = 
      `DELETE FROM ${MOVIES}
      WHERE id = ${movieId}`;
```

```
"should be able to delete movie",
    async done => {
      const movieId = 5915;
      const query = `DELETE FROM ${MOVIES}
      WHERE id = ${movieId}`;
```

So i have these two lines but i want to deleate on second and not to deleate on first, i know it has to do with update, cascade, delete, restrict, but i cant figure out or find more info about it right now... back end for this looks like

```
const CREATE_MOVIE_GENRES_TABLE = `
CREATE TABLE ${MOVIE_GENRES} (
  movie_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES movies(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  genre_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES genres(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  Primary key (movie_id, genre_id)
)`;
```

for more than one MOVIE tables

I know my delete from movies, section is wrong for sure... and i cant figure out right way for create table section as well

Comment: *i want to delete on second and not to delete on first...* why? What is the difference between movieIds 100 and 5915?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In short, what you have appears to be fine.**

Assuming that **100 *is mapped*** to one or more genres via the ***movies_genres*** table (first) and that **5915 *is NOT mapped*** to any genres via the ***movies_genres*** table then:-

- the first `DELETE FROM movies WHERE id=100` **will fail** due to the foreign key constraint conflict.
- the second `DELETE FROM movies WHERE id=5915` **will delete** the movie.
- updating 100 setting the id to 999 e.g. `UPDATE movies SET id=999 WHERE id=100` **will work** AND the update will be propagated to the ***movies_genres*** rows where the movie_id is 100 setting it to 999.
- updating 5915 setting the id to 55555 e.g. `UPDATE movies SET id=55555 WHERE id=5915` **will work**, there are no rows in movies_genres with movie_id as 5195.

**However**, if 5915 has mappings and you want to force it's deletion then you would have to delete the mappings from the movie_genres table and then delete 5915 e.g.

```
DELETE FROM movie_genres WHERE movie_id=5915;
```

followed by

```
DELETE FROM movies WHERE id=5915;
```

**Demonstration**

To demonstrate the above (noting that the order of updates/deletions suits a single run) :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS movie_genres;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS movies;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS genres;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS movies (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS genres (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE movie_genres (
  movie_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES movies(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  genre_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES genres(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  Primary key (movie_id, genre_id)
);

INSERT INTO movies VALUES (100,'Movie100'),(5915,'Movie5915'),(10,'Movie10');
INSERT INTO genres VALUES (1,'Genre1'),(2,'Genre2'),(3,'Genre3');
INSERT INTO movie_genres VALUES /* map movie 100 genre 1*/ (100,1), /* extras */(10,1),(10,2),(10,3);

UPDATE movies SET id = 55555 WHERE id = 5915;
UPDATE movies SET id = 999 WHERE id = 100;
/* reset id's */
UPDATE movies SET id=5915 WHERE id=5555;
UPDATE movies SET id=100 WHERE id=999;

/* Will delete as 5915 has no genres */
DELETE FROM movies WHERE id = 5915;

/* Reapply 5915 that was deleted and add mapppings to genres */
INSERT INTO movies VALUES (5915,'Movie5915');
INSERT INTO movie_genres VALUES /* map movie 5915 genre 1,2 and 3*/ (5915,1),(5915,2),(5915,3);

/* Force delete 5915 by-passing FK conflict i.e. doing the equivalent of cascade before deletion */
DELETE FROM movie_genres WHERE movie_id=5915;
DELETE FROM movies WHERE id= 5915;

/* DELETE WILL FAIL due to FK conflict */
DELETE FROM movies WHERE id = 100;
```

Running the above the message log :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS movie_genres
> OK
> Time: 0.186s


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS movies
> OK
> Time: 0.12s


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS genres
> OK
> Time: 0.074s


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS movies (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)
> OK
> Time: 0.084s


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS genres (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)
> OK
> Time: 0.122s    

CREATE TABLE movie_genres (
  movie_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES movies(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  genre_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES genres(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  Primary key (movie_id, genre_id)
)
> OK
> Time: 0.169s


INSERT INTO movies VALUES (100,'Movie100'),(5915,'Movie5915'),(10,'Movie10')
> Affected rows: 3
> Time: 0.084s


INSERT INTO genres VALUES (1,'Genre1'),(2,'Genre2'),(3,'Genre3')
> Affected rows: 3
> Time: 0.084s


INSERT INTO movie_genres VALUES /* map movie 100 genre 1*/ (100,1), /* extras */(10,1),(10,2),(10,3)
> Affected rows: 4
> Time: 0.084s



UPDATE movies SET id = 55555 WHERE id = 5915
> Affected rows: 1
> Time: 0.084s


UPDATE movies SET id = 999 WHERE id = 100
> Affected rows: 1
> Time: 0.096s

/* reset id's */
UPDATE movies SET id=5915 WHERE id=5555
> Affected rows: 0
> Time: 0s


UPDATE movies SET id=100 WHERE id=999
> Affected rows: 1
> Time: 0.096s


/* Will delete as 5915 has no genres */
DELETE FROM movies WHERE id = 5915
> Affected rows: 0
> Time: 0s


/* Reapply 5915 */
INSERT INTO movies VALUES (5915,'Movie5915')
> Affected rows: 1
> Time: 0.083s


INSERT INTO movie_genres VALUES /* map movie 5915 genre 1,2 and 3*/ (5915,1),(5915,2),(5915,3)
> Affected rows: 3
> Time: 0.096s


/* Force delete 5915 by-passing FK conflict i.e. doing the equivalent of cascade before deletion */
DELETE FROM movie_genres WHERE movie_id=5915
> Affected rows: 3
> Time: 0.107s


DELETE FROM movies WHERE id= 5915
> Affected rows: 1
> Time: 0.084s


/* Nothing to delete due to id change */
DELETE FROM movies WHERE id = 100
> FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
> Time: 0.003s
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks! I kinda had like 6 connected tabs, so i had to do 6 delete funtcions one by one to actaully get rid of the movie, and everything depending on it to erase all data for the lane, thx!